# The link of index.jsp in multimodule maven project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, web

Imade a multimodule maven project. Here is it's structure:

[image]

And now I wanna know a link to load my page in browser.
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxag12qilklvsg1/ear-1.0.ear) is my ear.jar to view the project more detail.

After deploying my ear-1.0.jar I've tryied to use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ear-1.0/web-1.0/` but it doesn't work = (

Please, give me the working link!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hooray!!! I have ve got the answer [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7)!!!

I created application.xml in ear-module with next content:

```
<application version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
    <module>
        <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>web-1.0.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/web</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

And now I can easily use `localhost:8080/web`!